# Múltiplas entradas no atributo class não funcionam

Tags: php, html, css

Quero mostrar um simples alert no php com bootstrap mas não estou conseguindo o código é esse:

```
echo "
<div class=alert alert-success role=alert>Logado com sucesso</div>
";
```

Porém está interpretando a classe da div assim:

```
<div class="alert" alert-success="" role="alert">Logado com sucesso</div>
```

Ele interpreta o `alert` separado. Como consigo trabalhar com 2 classes ou mais em uma div no php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário delimitar onde começa e onde terminam os valores para o atributo `class` isso é feito como com as aspas podem ser as simples ou duplas, como no `echo` está usando as duplas, use as simples ou use `\` para fazer os escapes:

Opção:

**Aspas simples:**

```
echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Logado com sucesso</div>";
```

**Escapes:**

```
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Logado com sucesso</div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta escapar as aspas:

```
echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Logado com sucesso</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Só como complemento da resposta do @rray, pois não tenho reputação ainda pra comentar, você pode simplemente fazer isso, também:

```
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Logado com sucesso</div>';
```

PHP suporta o uso tanto de [aspas simples como de aspas duplas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), e fazer uso das simples, quando a string a ser contida possuir muitas aspas duplas, fica mais fácil usar a simples para encapsular estas.